# nginx throws "504" gateway error when trying to run a phantomjs script from php

Tags: php, linux, nginx, phantomjs, server

I'm trying to run the phantomjs script like so:

```
$max_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
set_time_limit(0);
$result = shell_exec($path_to_phantomjs);
// Do stuff with result here...
set_time_limit($max_time);
```

It's a scraping script that takes a few minutes to complete but I want to wait for the result from it and manipulate it on my server. It is also important for me that this script will be run from the client-side and return some results to it for analysis etc.

This fails with a 504 error from nginx, it should be noted that the same code works well enough on my (local) apache server.

Answer (score 1):

504 error means nginx reaches timeout while getting page from backend (php). To fix this you should increase values of following variables in your php proxy location to value higher than time of executing your script (in seconds):

[fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout)

[proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)

Comment: I guess only one of them, probably first.